# How to create branches/trunks in cycles blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I would like some help with a problem I have been having with cycles blender! I am using Blender 2.79.

I am creating a realistic tree model using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGFGuL8bfdI&list=LLQivTFjh5_BJGNWA99UmUig&index=1&t=1189s

This is an older version of blender so I obviously take what he says with a grain of salt and use it as a base. I got to 19:20, and I ran into a problem. He started editing the trunk of the tree but it wouldn't select in my version of blender. I have been experimenting for a few days now and I haven't found a solution yet. I opened up the picture in rendered view and all I saw were the leaves I created and no branches or trunk.

I would appreciate any help in the matter! Thanks!

-Jinx[image: Picture of my screen w/ Rendered/non-rendered/wireframe]

Comment: What is your question? There is curve for the trunk on your screenshot and starting from that same moment in the video you link he explains how to make that curve trunk rendered (since unbeveled curve has no geometry and can't be rendered).

Comment: Could it be that you have the visibility/selectably turned off for the mesh? Check that in the outliner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. Zak was correct. The curve on the trunk did have to be beveled and after fiddling with the settings for a bit I was finally able to figure it out. I had a weird setting on that wouldn't allow me to select the trunk but after some time I was able to turn it off and do as was instructed in the video. Mr. Leo was also correct in that I had in settings the visibility turned off as well.